# How do I block internet access (not LAN) to/from an IoT device?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have couple of IoT bulbs. I have installed an "local" integration in (Home assistant) for the IoT devices.

Now I don't want them to connect to internet only through LAN. How do I do that?

I have the feeling that would be easy if I should have a little more advanced router!?
I have Google WiFi router which has limited settings.

Is there a command (command prompt (Windows) or (terminal (Linux) that can accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is far too confusing - "Now i dont want them to connect to internet only through lan" - What **do** you want to do?

Comment: Unless those windows or linux systems is acting as a router or controller (and it doesn't appear they are), no setting on them could affect the lightbulbs. Instead find out the IP addresses of the lightbulbs, and use the firewall on the wifi router to block them outbound so they can't send traffic to devices outside your LAN.

Comment: You can make DHCP reservations in your router to give your IoT devices fixed IP addresses in a specific range and block that range from sending traffic outside your network with the built-in firewall or IP filter in your router, if your router supports that. I’m not familiar with the Google WiFi router and I’m not sure it supports this however.